# SSH through multiple hosts in go

Tags: ssh, go, cryptography

Is it possible to SSH to another host while in an SSH session in golang? I tried chaining some stuff together like this, but the printout says the remote addr of client 2 is 0.0.0.0 and an error is given when I try to execute anything on an ssh.Session from client2.

```
host1 := "host1.com"
host2 := "host2.com"
client1, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", host, config)
if err != nil {
    panic("Failed to dial: " + err.Error())
}

conn, err := client1.Dial("tcp", host2)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

sshConn, newChan, requestChan, err := ssh.NewClientConn(conn, host2, config)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

client2 := ssh.NewClient(sshConn, newChan, requestChan)

fmt.Println("Client 2 RemoteAddr():", client2.RemoteAddr())
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are running all of this code on the same host. Let's call the host you run your app on `host0` for convenience.

You start out making a connection from `host0` to `host1`. That works fine. What you seem to want to do next is make a connection from `host1` to `host2`. To do that you need to run the SSH code on `host1`. But your app, which is and always has been running on `host0`, is not in the place to do that.

You will need to put a program on `host1` that does the connection to `host2` and then send a command down the SSH connection to `host1` that will start that program.